# How to open calendar view in many2one field for odoo 10

Tags: calendar, odoo, odoo-10, many-to-one

Like Form and list view, Can it is possible to open calendar view in many2one field. If it is possible then please suggest a model or way to open calendar view in many2one field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may increase your chances to receive an answer by providing what you have tried. E.g. the configuration where you open a list view now, but would like to open a calendar view instead.